# Bloodhound html file changes are not affecting in ui

Tags: apache-bloodhound

I am working on ui bloodhound changes. I have to remove logo of apache bloodhound and header tabs in the dashboard. I made the changes in bloodhound_theme-> bhtheme-> templates-> bloodhound_theme.html, this location file but no changes have been made in ui. after running the server. I checked in the google i didnt get any material regarding it. If anyone knows the way to make a changes in bloodhound ui manually please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bloodhound is built on Trac, so most of the Trac documentation applies.

You can modify aspects of the header using [configuration options](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracIni#header_logo-section), so modifying a template may not be necessary. See also [this documentation](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#Logo).

To modify templates you should follow the instructions [TracInterfaceCustomization](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#SiteAppearance). In short, you should put a copy of the template in the Environment `templates` directory.

Keep in mind for any modifications to js and css files, particularly if you followed the [installation instructions](https://live.bloodhound.apache.org/bloodhound/products/BHD/wiki/BloodhoundInstall#WebServer) to install Bloodhound: you'll need to re-run the `deploy` command to extract static assets to the location from which they are served.

```
$ trac-admin /opt/bloodhound/environments/main/ deploy /opt/bloodhound/environments/main/site
```